# Can you recommend suction-cup microphone holder ?

Tags: microphone, microphone-stand, car, vehicles, recording

Can you recommend suction-cup microphone holder ?
Recording cars etc...

Answer (score 3):

I use a pair or Manfrotto pump-cups, and have never had one fall off.  They are 60mm in diameter, and you need to remember to take something with you to clean the surface afterwards as they usually leave a visible ring.

http://www.manfrotto.com/pump-cup-with-flat-base

Answer (score 1):

I used for this standard camera car rig suction caps - 2 for boom pole, 1 for single microphone on mic holder.
Follow this video: http://vimeo.com/33421306